# How can I understand where the final 'async' keyword goes in the tree of async-awaits?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

This is something that always confuses me about `async-await`. Whenever I create a function that uses `await`, that function must have the modifier `async`. But then a function that `await`s ***that*** function must also be marked `async`. It's an endless chain. Can someone help me understand how the chain ends?

Comment: Console app, MVC, WPF, Windows Forms, or Web API?

Comment: call `await` when you need to get the value of `T` for a method that returns `Taks<T>`.  So if your method returns Task<T>, but that method doesn't use T, you can just return Task<T>

Comment: In case the duplicate does not answer your question, in general it ends:

1. either with a method that does not await (which means that after calling `async` method, and after the first blocking await in that method, it continues the execution)

2. or with a method which uses a different mechanism to block the execution (not `await`), e.g.

`Task task = DoAsync();
task.Wait();`

Comment: I have a related question: every method either throws, goes into an infinite loop, or it returns, and a method which returns simply transfers control to *another* method.  Therefore every program either crashes or runs forever. How is it possible that any program ever ends without crashing?  Funnily enough, the answer to my question and the answer to your question are the same.

Comment: @EricLippert: "every method either throws, goes into an infinite loop, or it returns". `Environment.FailFast`? :-)

Comment: @LucaCremonesi: Indeed. More generally: the supposition that every method returns to another method or runs forever is false. I'm hoping that the original poster will examine the suppositions that (1) the caller of an async method must await the result; there is no such requirement, and (2) that every method returns normally; again, there is no such requirement.